# UE4 C++ convert string to double

Tags: c++, variables, unreal-engine4

I want to make a server system in my Unreal Projekt. I want to download a file with all the player locations from the Server and open the file to read the lines. It's working fine to this moment. Then I have to split the lines for all the players coordinates.

I don't know how I can convert an **FString** into an **double** to create then an **FVector** out of the coordinates.

Comment: How are the coordinates formatted?

Answer (score 5):

The [operator*](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FString/op_deref/index.html) for an `FString` returns a `TCHAR *` that you can later use with [C strings handling functions](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Misc/TCString/index.html), e.g.

```
double my_double = FCString::Atod(*my_fstring);
```